# show text below image in android webview

Tags: android, webview

In my application I am using webview, In this webview I am setting data. This data contains one image and some line of text. My problem is that if image is small then text starts from right hand side of image and if image is large then text starts below image. I want to display all text data below image. How  to do this in webview? my xml file which contains webview is as:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context="test.material.com.retrofitdemo3.NewsArticleFragment">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"/>

<include
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/layout_error"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutError"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your java code too

Comment: @PPD: There is nothing specific to WebView in this question. Just insert `<br>` tag after the `<img>` tag in your HTML, and this will force the text following the image to start on a new line.